# About css float left for div1, the appearance of div2?

Tags: html, css

This is the html code.

```
<div id="sidebar1">
     sidebar1 
</div>
 <div id="sidebar2">
      sidebar2  
</div>
```

This is the css code for the html.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;

}

 div#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
}
```

The presentation of it looks like below in my latest firefox. 
Why was the text 'sidebar2' not hidden by the div1?

[image]

The original html looked like below.

[image]

In my opinion, due to the float left, the entire div2 will be overlapped by div1 including the text in div2 like below.

[image]

the below picture is the moment when I hover to the div2 in firebug. Obviously, the text 'siderbar2' seems depart from the div2. why?
[image]

Comment: what do you mean, hidden by div1? do you want it to go behind div1 or what?

Comment: In my opinion, the text in the div2 will be overlapped by div1 due to this float left? because the whole div2 has been overlapped by div1

Comment: what you do with float left on both elements, is pushing them next to each other, that is the whole point of float. and you can say something like `clear: both` or `clear: none` to get them next to or above and below each other.

Comment: Obviously, in my sample, the div2 actually exists, it is merely covered by div1, however, why the text in div2 not covered by div1?

Comment: It looks like you didnt really understand what float actually does or we didnt understood what you really want... When floating both elements left you will have the sidebars next to each other: |sidebar1|sidebar2|

Comment: last question, after floating left, the text 'sidebar2' belong to ?

Comment: @liamxu See my answer. The text "sidebar2" belongs to the first line box of the `#sidebar2` block.

Answer (score 3):

To get the problem, you need to understand that **the box is not the content**.

[From W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing#Some_boring_theory):

> Each rendered line is enclosed in a separate line box.

- You make `#sidebar1` floating, so you put it out of the flow
- Now, `#sidebar2` box can take its place
- **But**, `#sidebar2`'s content (aka. first line box) is different from `#sidebar2` box, and was pushed down by `#sidebar1`

To avoid this kind of behavior, you can add `overflow: hidden` on `#sidebar2`, or better: `float: left`.

---

Many people doesn't understand `float` and don't think it put the element out of the flow. The way we use it usually makes us to think it simply "puts elements next to each other". And when we face an "issue", we solve it without understanding it.

This property's name is `float`, not `arrange`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two elements to display over each other. Change the positioning of the first one to absolute.

This will take it out of the ordinary flow rendering and allow any elements to overlap with it.

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    position:absolute;
}

 div#sidebar1 {
    float: left;
}
```